# JasperReports Server 6.2 - Error 400:bad request - User creation with roles REST v2

Tags: rest, jasperserver

I am not sure what is going wrong with the create user api with roles.

Observations:

1. When fired without the roles it works fine, the payload is given below

   ```
   {
   "fullName": "unittestuser",
   "emailAddress": null,
   "enabled": true,
   "password": "39HN=K?E",
   "roles": null
   }
   ```
2. when same endpoint is invoked with the addition of roles then it fails giving the http error code 400 (bad request)

   ```
   {
     "fullName": "unittestuser",
     "emailAddress": null,
     "enabled": true,
     "password": "39HN=K?E",
     "roles": [
       {      "name": "unittest"    },
       {      "name": "UsernamePasswordAuthentication"    },
       {      "name": "Platform_NamedUser"    },
       {      "name": "Platform_Anyone"    },
       {      "name": "Platform_Metadata_MetadataInitializeUser"    }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. The roles part works when the default roles shipped with JasperReports Server installation are sent.

   ```
   {
     "fullName": "unittestuser3",
     "emailAddress": null,
     "externallyDefined": false,
     "enabled": true,
     "password": "39HN=K?E",
      "roles": [
       {      "name": "ROLE_USER"    },
        {      "name": "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"    }
     ]
   }
   ```

I have checked the the new roles which I have created are present on the *JR Server* before the create user is hit, so I am not sure what is going wrong with the newly created roles. I am using REST api v2 for role creation as well as user creation.

I have also tried creation the user first with empty roles and then adding roles the update call still fails with the same error.

Let me know if anyone has a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed...the new 6.0 on wards requires tenantid to be passed with the name of the role.
So instead of:
`{      "name": "unittest"    }`

I passed: `{      "name": "unittest", "tenantId": "myorg"    }`